# Display Play framework test when running in test mode

Tags: playframework

Is there any way I can disable/skip all Play's own unit test when I run the "play test".

I am blocked by this stupid Guice compilation error.

Comment: Did you find a solution for the problem? Cheers, Martin

Answer (score 1):

i know it is an old question but i think there are lots of people stuck with guice modules test error.

The solution is to load dependencies in production mode, so play will automatically delete the tests folder found in guice module.

you can also delete the tests folder in the guice module by yourself but i think its a better way to let play do this job.

just type:

```
play deps --forProd
```